# Formatar mascara para CNPJ

Tags: javascript, asp.net

estou precisando formatar um mascara para CNPJ. Até ai esta feito, mas o padrão da empresa é formatar com espaço ao invés de ponto.

Este é o código que estou usando.

```
valorDoTextBox = valorDoTextBox.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2.$3")
```

Alguém pode me explicar com funciona esta parte `(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2.$3")` para que possa tirar os ponto e colocar um espaço.

obrigado que poder me ajudar.

```
function MascaraParaLabel(valorDoTextBox) {

        if (valorDoTextBox.length <= 14) {  

            //Coloca ponto entre o segundo e o terceiro dígitos
            valorDoTextBox = valorDoTextBox.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1.$2")

            //Coloca ponto entre o quinto e o sexto dígitos
            valorDoTextBox = valorDoTextBox.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1 $2 $3")

            //Coloca uma barra entre o oitavo e o nono dígitos
            valorDoTextBox = valorDoTextBox.replace(/\.(\d{3})(\d)/, ".$1/$2")

            //Coloca um hífen depois do bloco de quatro dígitos
            valorDoTextBox = valorDoTextBox.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1-$2") 
        } 
        return valorDoTextBox
```

Eu passo o valor do textbox sem formatar 14397462000109 e a label que fica na frente, mostra 14 397 462/0001-09 formatado na padrão da empresa.

Comment: Eu tire os ponto mas não funcionou , e fica tudo fora do lugar.

Comment: Eu passo o valor do textbox sem formatar 14397462000109 e a label que fica na frente, mostra 14 397 462/0001-09 formatado na padrão da empresa.

Comment: Usando este jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/jn8rpev0/ podes explicar que passos não estão a funcionar e como queres que funcione?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu fiz esse código, achei que ficou simples.

```js
    document.getElementById('produto-1-cnpj').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
      var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,2})/);
      e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '.' + x[2] + '.' + x[3] + '/' + x[4] + (x[5] ? '-' + x[5] : '');
    });
```

```html
<input id="produto-1-cnpj" class="form-control rounded-form" type="text" placeholder="Insira o CNPJ da sua loja" maxlength="18"/>
```

Answer (score 21):

Pra formatar de uma vez só, você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
"14397462000109".replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{2})/, "$1 $2 $3/$4-$5")
```

Vai resultar em `14 397 462/0001-09`.

Agora, caso você utilize uma máscara de input na digitação, pode utilizar algo como:

```
$("input").on("keyup", function(e)
{
    $(this).val(
        $(this).val()
        .replace(/\D/g, '')
        .replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{3})?(\d{3})?(\d{4})?(\d{2})?/, "$1 $2 $3/$4-$5"));
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyvfemw7/)**</kbd>

A diferença na regex é que deixei do segundo grupo em diante como opcional, adicionando o `?` depois de cada um. Não é uma máscara perfeita de input, mas você pode melhorar ela limitando outros caracteres etc.

Comment: DontVoteMeDown, obrigado pela ajudar, consegui resolver o me problema com a solução proposta por você e pelo  Sergio. Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda.

Comment: @krispim Ok, que bom que deu certo. Se essa for a resposta correta você pode marca-la, ou se o Sergio contribuiu mais, peça pra ele postar uma resposta pra que você possa marca-la.

Comment: Eu não fiz nada de especial, só criei um jsFiddle para ajudar a diagnosticar o problema :) . Por mim está resposta é válida e pode ser aceite se resolveu o problema. (cc @krispim)

Answer (score -3):

utilizando a função feita pelo @Dr.G, eu apenas adicionei um if que checa se os valores passados no input são sequências, assim evitamos números em sequência como cnpj. Na minha função está pegando todos os inputs com name=cnpj, ou seja, se vc tiver mais de um form com input de cnpj na página ele pega e aplica a máscara neles

```
var input_cnpj = document.querySelectorAll('[name="CNPJ"]');
      
input_cnpj.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,2})/);
    e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '.' + x[2] + '.' + x[3] + '/' + x[4] + (x[5] ? '-' + x[5] : '');
    console.log(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value) {
      if (e.target.value == "00.000.000/0000-00" || 
        e.target.value == "11.111.111/1111-11" || 
        e.target.value == "22.222.222/2222-22" || 
        e.target.value == "33.333.333/3333-33" || 
        e.target.value == "44.444.444/4444-44" || 
        e.target.value == "55.555.555/5555-55" || 
        e.target.value == "66.666.666/6666-66" || 
        e.target.value == "77.777.777/7777-77" || 
        e.target.value == "88.888.888/8888-88" || 
        e.target.value == "99.999.999/9999-99") {
          // el.value = ''
          e.target.value = ''
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

@Sergio

Olá.
Não tem variável global.
Segue um exemplo, você pode fazer mudanças caso não lhe atenda. Onde tem "os pontos do cpf", coloquei "espaço".

```
obj = o; //variavel recebe o//
fun = f; //variavel recebe f//
setTimeout("execMascara()", 1);
}

function execMascara() {
    obj.value = fun(obj.value);
}

function cpf(cpf) {
    mascara = cpf.replace(/\D/g, "");
    mascara = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1 $2");
    mascara = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1 $2");
    mascara = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1 $2");

    return mascara;
}
```

No formulário:

```
<label="cpf">
CPF: <input onkeypress="mascara(this, cpf)" maxlength="14"/>
</label>
```

Comment: André dei `-1` pois acho essa resposta errada, pelo menos com problemas. Tem erros de sintaxe no JavaScript e variáveis globais. Repara que o nome da função é `cpf` e estás a usar o mesmo nome para uma variável dentro da função. Se corrigires dá-me um toque com "@Sergio" que tenho gosto em rever e votar de novo.

Comment: @Sergio [este é o código original](http://elcio.com.br/ajax/mascara/). Creio que tenha sido(mal) copiado desse post.