# Criar máscara para um texto

Tags: javascript, html, mvc

Preciso retornar um valor de CNPJ com uma máscara através do Javascript para um texto em uma tag td do meu código html. O valor é retornado do bd sem formatação padrão de CNPJ como no código abaixo:

```
<tr th:each="cliente : ${clientes}" class="cliente">
<td id="#cnpj" th:text="${cliente.cnpj}" class="cnpjTd"></td>
<td id="#razaosocial" th:text="${cliente.razaoSocial}"></td>
```

Por exemplo: o cliente cnpj retorna um valor "11111111111111" e preciso que seja formatado como "11.111.111/1111-11".

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77505/formatar-mascara-para-cnpj , https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177760/como-se-faz-máscara-para-exibição-de-fone-cnpj-cpf-etc-no-laravel, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94956/máscara-para-cpf-e-cnpj-no-mesmo-campo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenho um código aqui que sempre costumo usar e me salva muito.. Segue ele abaixo, basta você chamar a função com o valor que você deseja.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mascarar").click(function(){
      $("#depois").html(Mascara($('#antes').html()));
    });
  });
  function Mascara(valorFormatar) {
    //Coloca ponto entre o segundo e o terceiro dígitos
    valorFormatar=valorFormatar.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1.$2")

    //Coloca ponto entre o quinto e o sexto dígitos
    valorFormatar=valorFormatar.replace(/^(\d{2})\.(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2.$3")

    //Coloca uma barra entre o oitavo e o nono dígitos
    valorFormatar=valorFormatar.replace(/\.(\d{3})(\d)/,".$1/$2")

    //Coloca um hífen depois do bloco de quatro dígitos
    valorFormatar=valorFormatar.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/,"$1-$2")

    return valorFormatar;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Dado antes</h2>

  <p id="antes">09673442000173</p>

  <h2>Dado depois</h2>

  <p id="depois"></p>

  <button type="button" id="mascarar">Formatar!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```